# OSError: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, when running python command under non-root user

Tags: permissions, conda

My environments:

- Ubuntu 22.04 AMD64
- NVIDIA-SMI 525.147.05   Driver Version: 525.147.05   CUDA Version: 12.0
- In the file ~/.bashrc, there are:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
export LIBRARY_PATH="${CUDA_HOME}/lib64"
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="${CUDA_HOME}/include"
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

When I installed https://github.com/PKU-YuanGroup/MoE-LLaVA with non-root user, it showed errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 168, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I switched to the root user and conda create a new environment and run *pip install .* successfully and run the programm without error.

However, when I switched back to the normal user to run a *python ***.py *command which was working before I installed the above project with the root user, it showed errors the same as the above. It seems sth about permissions, other than the problem of the CUDA version.

I googled some posts in the Stackoverflow, no satisfactory answer. I also run `sudo chmod 777 -R on /usr/local/cuda`, no luck.
I had to apt purge all things about CUDA and Nvidia, then reinstall those staff according official tutorial, then the un-working program get working again under non-root user.

**What I want**: I can run pip install *** under a non-root user in any conda environment without the error above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.